# SQL Server Windows Auth in a Desktop application - connection error

Tags: c#, sql-server

our c# based desktop application is throwing the following error while connecting the SQL Server 2008 with Windows authentication for a single user.
But the same user can access the same database from another ASP.NET application. Other user can access both the apps.

the connection str is:

```
string sqlConnSTR = "Data Source=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx,100;Initial Catalog=xxx_DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - A non-recoverable error occurred during a
>   database lookup.)

Any idea, why a single user cannot access database from desktop application but from Browser based application?

Comment: Are the desktop application, the server application and the database server on 3 different computers?

Comment: Are you really using port 100?

Comment: Yes, all are in diffrent machine and users are in Active directory.

Comment: I am using Domain Name instead IP address in my real application, it only for example. and the port is 10110.

Answer (score 0):

Try PC Name or Domain Name as Datasource in connection string instead of IP Address